# Difference between Websphere Application server and Websphere commerce server

Tags: java, server, websphere-7

We are trying to install a patch to the Websphere Application Server. But have got the instructions for Websphere commerce server. so just wondering if both are same and the same instruction can be applied.

Do we need root access for doing any Websphere installation or owner access to the websphere installation directory would do the job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere Commerce is using WebSphere Application Server underneath, but is not the same and patching instructions might be different.

You can find installation instruction with each assosiated fixpack here:
[Fix list for IBM WebSphere Application Server V7.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27014463#70037)

For general instruction about installing fixpacks and interim fixes see here:

[Installing maintenance packages, interim fixes, fix packs, and refresh packs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.installation.soafepnd.doc/info/ae/ae/tins_ptfLevels.html?lang=en)

Regarding `root` user - you should use the same user that was used during the installation - if it was root then use root, if it was your dedicated user then use the same user.

Comment: We are able to run the patch without much trouble, Am just curious; if there is a way to find which files got affected from the patch. Is there a way to validate a patch update. I could see the logs that the installation is success. But how do we physically verify it ?

Comment: @Jeslinedias Run the` versionInfo.bat/sh` script with `-fixpackDetail`. You can additionally format it in html if you prefer `-format html`

Comment: I have multiple versionInfo.sh file available.                                                                   ./opt/.IHS70029/IHS/ihs.primary.pak/repository/wasproduct.bin/bin/versionInfo.sh
./opt/.IHS70029/Plugin/plg.plgmain.pak/repository/wasproduct.plugin.bin/bin/versionInfo.sh
./opt/.IHS70029/updateinstaller/bin/versionInfo.sh
./opt/IHS70029/Plugins/bin/versionInfo.sh
./opt/IHS70029/bin/versionInfo.sh
./v700/bin/versionInfo.sh                                                                                                        is '-fixpackDetail' a generic parameter ? which is right ?

Comment: @Jeslinedias It is in the installation folder - usually `/WebSphere/AppServer/bin` not IHS.